# Deriving general boundary conditions from first principles for elastodynamic scattering

Tags: mathematical-physics, scattering, boundary-conditions, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

It seems that most of the relevant books only give the linear case and the rest say something along the lines of "here are common examples of boundary conditions."
What are the most general boundary conditions for elastic waves incident on a boundary between two elastic solids, and how does one derive them from first principles?
Also, does the case have to be linear in order to not have to account for thermal effects?
If not, please exclude thermal effects.

Update:
For those pursuing a similar question, I found a book (Nonlinear Continuum Mechanics and Large Inelastic Deformations by Dimitrienko) that very general boundary conditions from first principles, but the derivation scattered throughout the first five chapters.

So, for those who may be able to answer, It will take me a while to extract it all and write in a clear and meaningful way.  If anyone can do so in the meanwhile, please do.  Providing parts of the derivation, or even particular cases, may help piece together the final answer.  Please do so.

And back to those pursuing a similar question, the nonlinear case does not necessitate thermal effects.

Comment: How to derive them -- what are the dependent variables? What is the order of the ODE/PDE? That determines the number of the BC's on each variable. And the physical behavior that needs to happen determines the type.

Comment: I'm looking for boundary conditions that include all elastic possibilities, except thermoelastic, unless including nonlinear possibilities requires thermoelastic considerations.  Then I would like to know how they are derived.  For example, are there avenues equivalent to pillbox method using Maxwell equations for the nonlinear case?